# Compute Superset of Sequences

Tags: c#, .net

Given any number of sequences I need to compute a superset "containing the input sequences".

The result must be minimum in length and the order of the input elements must not be changed. Items of the input must not necessarily be kept together.

A comparison is provided to determine precedence of any symbol / element when needed during computation.

Curious what the particular problem is called in number theory.

Preferably I'd like to solve this making use of .NET Types and IEnumerable Extensions.

Example with the comparison based on the alphabet:

```
ABC, ABC -> ABC

ABC, ABD -> ABCD

ABCD, BCD, ACD, ACB -> ABCDB

ABCD, EBCD -> AEBCD
```

My approach so far, not slving the last one (ABCD, EBCD)

```
namespace Ra.Essentials
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;

   public static class SequenceReductionExtensions
   {
      public static IEnumerable<T> Reduce<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input)
      {
         return input.Reduce(Comparer<T>.Default.Compare);
      }

      public static IEnumerable<T> Reduce<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input, Comparison<T> comparison)
      {
         var enumerators = input.Select(o => o.GetEnumerator()).ToList();

         enumerators.RemoveAll(o => !o.MoveNext());

         while (enumerators.Any())
         {
            var symbols = enumerators.GroupBy(o => o.Current);

            // review: orderby key
            var spread = symbols.GroupBy(o => o.Count()).OrderByDescending(o => o.Count());

            T ret;

            var firstSpread = spread.First();

            // gleiche Anzahl verschiedener Symbole
            if (firstSpread.Count() > 1)
            {
               var a1 = firstSpread.First().Key;
               var a2 = firstSpread.Skip(1).First().Key;

               ret = comparison(a1, a2) < 0 ? a1 : a2;
            }
            else
            {
               ret = firstSpread.First().Key;
            }

            enumerators.RemoveAll(o => comparison(o.Current, ret) == 0 && !o.MoveNext());

            yield return ret;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And Unit Test:

```
namespace Ra.Essentials.Tests
{
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using NUnit.Framework;
   using XBase.Essentials;

   [TestFixture]
   public class SequenceReductionExtensionsTests
   {
      [TestCase("ABC", new[] { "ABC" })]
      [TestCase("ABC", new[] { "ABC", "ABC" })]
      [TestCase("ABCD", new[] { "ABC", "ABD" })]
      [TestCase("ABCDB", new[] { "ABCD", "BCD", "ACD", "ACB" })]
      [TestCase("AEBCD", new[] { "ABCD", "EBCD" })]
      public void Should_Reduce(string expected, IEnumerable<string> input)
      {
         "Ex:".ToOutput();
         expected.ToOutput();

         "In:".ToOutput();
         input.ForEach(o => o.ToOutput());

         CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, CallReduce(input));
      }

      private static string CallReduce(IEnumerable<string> input)
      {
         var sequences = input.Select(o => o.ToList());

         return string.Join(string.Empty, sequences.Reduce(Comparer<char>.Default.Compare));
      }
   }
```

}

Comment: How do you know it's ABCD and not ABDC (second example)? Why AEBCD and not EABCD (fourth example)? What have you yourself tried to do your homework?

Comment: Added code sample of my homework, the order of symbols is determined by a comparison

Comment: ...more precisely, the precedence of any symbol, when in doubt, is denoted by the comparison function.

Comment: I don't think, the last case is solvable without some backtracking or similar. Consider the situation, where you have taken the `A` from the first string. Now you have to decide whether to take the `B` from the first or `E` from the second. To know that you must take the `E` here, you must look ahead after the `E` to discover that it's followed `BCD` which is also the remaining part of the first string. Maybe you'll have to find the correct sequence starting from the end. But I'm not quite sure how. But to be honest, if I'm not overseeing something, this is quite challenging.

Comment: @Mart Did you manage to solve this? I am in a similar situation. I need to use sequence examples to establish a master sequence that, if used as a sorting authority on the sub sets without ordering, would reproduce their sequence.